# How to concat a list of integers to a string in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have this tuple that looks like this:

```
{127,0,0,1}
```

Now I want to pass that tuple as the string `"127.0.0.1"` to an external lib (a geo IP lib). What's the best way to convert this tuple to the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ip_to_string({I1, I2, I3, I4}) ->
    lists:concat([I1,".",I2,".",I3,".",I4]);
ip_to_string({v6, Addr}) ->
    inet_parse:ntoa(Addr).
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always use **inet_parse:ntoa/1**:

```
1> inet_parse:ntoa({127,0,0,1}).
"127.0.0.1"
2> inet_parse:ntoa({0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}).
"::1"
```