# How to join a list of integers to a string in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have a list of integers:

```erlang
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].
```

I'd like to get the string `"1 2 3 4 5 6"` as the output.

I've tried `string:join(X, " ")` but it doesn't work.

I've also tried `_X = lists:join(X, " "),` but it is resulting in an empty string " ". When I print it `erlang:display(_X).`

Is there a built-in method in Erlang that does that?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25859835/8608146

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `string:join/2` and `lists:join/2` will produce the desired result, but both require the integers to be converted to strings first. You can use a list comprehension to do that:

```
1> X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
2> string:join([integer_to_list(I) || I <- X], " ").
"1 2 3 4 5 6"
3> lists:join(" ", [integer_to_list(I) || I <- X]).
["1"," ","2"," ","3"," ","4"," ","5"," ","6"]
4> lists:flatten(lists:join(" ", [integer_to_list(I) || I <- X])).
"1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

Note that `lists:join/2` takes the separator as its first argument while `string:join/2` takes it as the second argument.

Note also that `lists:join/2` returns a new list where the elements of the input list are separated by the separator. To get a flat list when, as in this case, the separator is also a list, use `lists:flatten/1` as shown in the final command above.

And finally, note that [`string:join/2` is obsolete](https://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#join-2), and you should use `lists:join/2` instead.